# How to use Do-Not-Track-Me cookie to disable tracking

Tags: cookies, matomo, contao

I am using cookiebar extension for cookie management of my contao site. For disabling piwik , can I use Do-Not-Track-Me .Then,How can I use it?
The google analytics can be disabled like

```
window['ga-disable-<?= $GoogleAnalyticsId ?>'] = !!localStorage.getItem('COOKIEBAR_ANALYTICS');
```

Comment: You are mixing up multiple things. DoNotTrack is a browser setting. Matomo supports an opt-out cookie or an opt-in consent feature: https://developer.matomo.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#asking-for-consent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the "Do-Not-Track" setting of the browser. The cookiebar extension uses its own setting in the local storage of the browser.

You can simply wrap your Matomo tracking code with

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('COOKIEBAR_ANALYTICS')) {
    …
}
```

for example.

I am not sure what the advantage of using `window['ga-disable-…']` is, instead of a simple `if () {}`.

Comment: I got window['ga-disable-…'] from https://github.com/codefog/contao-cookiebar/blob/master/docs/README.md